# unable to send flask data to database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How to send flask data to the database. I created the **.html form** but unable to perform the connectivity. All functions are written in the app.py.

.html code:

```
<div id="registration">
<h2 style = "text-align: center;">Registration Form</h2>
    <form class="website form-horizontal container-fluid mt32" action=" " method="post">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 text-right" style="padding:1%;">
          <label class="control-label" for="name"> Your Name*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8" style="padding:1%;">
          <input class="form-control o_website_form_input" name="username" required="True" autocorrect="off" type="text"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 text-right" style="padding:1%;">
          <label class="control-label" for="email_from">Your Email*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8" style="padding:1%;">
          <input class="form-control o_website_form_input" name="email" required="True" autocorrect="off" type="email"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

How to give connectivity using mysql, SQLAlchemy etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `route` with `POST` method, so you can post the data from your `html` form to it.

```
@app.route('/add_post', methods=['POST'])
def add_post():
    # get the form from request and add it to db
```

it is optional, but better to make your form with `wtforms` (`Flask-WTF`). it would handle form creating in an easy to read and much safer way.

then, you need to use either `sqlalchemy` or even easier and better `flask-sqlalchemy` extension. create a `class` of type `Model`(`Base` if you use bare `sqlalchemy`). this class would represent your tables in the database.

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120)
```

and then, you can add a post to the db like:

```
post = Post(title="my post title")
db.session.add(post)
db.session.commit()
```

and you can query your database with:

```
posts = Post.query.all()
```

`sqlalchemy` and `flask-sqlalchemy` would connect you to engines such as `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sqlite`, etc.

you can read the documentations for frameworks on how to do all of this.